# MethodInfo Equality for Declaring Type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to check equality between two MethodInfos. They are actually the exact same MethodInfo with the exception of the ReflectedType (that is, the DeclaringType is the same and the methods should actually have the same body). There are a number of ways of doing this, but I'm looking for the most efficient.

Right now I have:

```
    public static bool AreMethodsEqualForDeclaringType(this MethodInfo first, MethodInfo second)
    {
        first = first.ReflectedType == first.DeclaringType ? first : first.DeclaringType.GetMethod(first.Name, first.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
        second = second.ReflectedType == second.DeclaringType ? second : second.DeclaringType.GetMethod(second.Name, second.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
        return first == second;
    }
```

This is kind of expensive, so I'm wondering if there's a better way...

Should I be comparing the two method bodies instead? eg.

```
first.GetMethodBody() == second.GetMethodBody()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just compare the declaring types directly without comparing hem to the reflected types? I'm also interested in knowing why you need to so this.

Comment: Definitely could just compare the declaring types, but it's more expensive because that requires calling GetParameters(), whereas, if the ReflectedTypes are equal, I can just do a regular equality check.

Comment: I need to do this because I have Proxy classes created by EntityFramework at runtime that I'm doing some reflection on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess I'll leave my answer as the answer to the question...

One thing to note:

```
first.GetMethodBody() == second.GetMethodBody()
```

does NOT work...so the only answer I've found to date is:

```
public static bool AreMethodsEqualForDeclaringType(this MethodInfo first, MethodInfo second)
{
    first = first.ReflectedType == first.DeclaringType ? first : first.DeclaringType.GetMethod(first.Name, first.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
    second = second.ReflectedType == second.DeclaringType ? second : second.DeclaringType.GetMethod(second.Name, second.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
    return first == second;
}
```

Comment: the method body has a byte[] that is the IL of the method body, you can compare those byte by byte instead of using just "==".

Comment: @Jeff. I know I'm a decade or so late to the party but ... are you still using this code successfully? I need something similar but not looking to invent a wheel. [Ayende has a posting on this](http://ayende.com/blog/2658/method-equality) that you surely must have seen. Appreciate any feedback. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Would comparing the [MetadataToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.metadatatoken.aspx) and [Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.module.aspx) help?

The documentation of MetadataToken describes it as: "A value which, in combination with Module, uniquely identifies a metadata element."

So far I've found it to be working for comparing equal-except-for-ReflectedType MemberInfo instances. But I did not test it for cases like generic method definitions.

Comment: Thanks, but that's specifically the case where is doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

this code works when you try to equal class and interface method:

```
    static bool EquelMethods(MethodInfo method1, MethodInfo method2)
    {
        var find = method1.DeclaringType.GetMethod(method2.Name, method2.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
        return find != null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here will fail when dealing with generics.

In particular they will have issues when one of the following is true:

1. When different overloads with the same parameters differ only with the generic count
2. When comparing generic method definition to a constructed method
3. When comparing constructed generic methods that were constructed with different type parameters

Here is a solution that covers all these cases:

```
static bool IsEqual(MethodInfo methodInfo, MethodInfo other)
{
    if (methodInfo.ReflectedType == other.ReflectedType) return methodInfo == other;
    if (methodInfo.DeclaringType != other.DeclaringType) return false;

    return methodInfo.Name == other.Name
        && methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType)
               .SequenceEqual(other.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType))
        && methodInfo.GetGenericArguments()
               .SequenceEqual(other.GetGenericArguments());
}
```