# RuntimeMethodInfo equality: bug?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Lets start with:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    class A
    {
        public virtual void Do() { }
    }

    class B:A
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var m1 = typeof(A).GetMethod("Do");
        var m2 = typeof(B).GetMethod("Do");

        Console.WriteLine("Methods are equal?\t\t{0}", m1 == m2);
        Console.WriteLine("Method handles are equal?\t{0}", m1.MethodHandle == m2.MethodHandle);

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

([try it online](http://ideone.com/G8cyZ7) at ideone)

So, there are two unequal `MethodInfo` instances, both containing the same method handle. Here's [the equals operator source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodinfo.cs#52):

```
public static bool operator ==(MethodInfo left, MethodInfo right)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        return true;

    if ((object)left == null || (object)right == null ||
        left is RuntimeMethodInfo || right is RuntimeMethodInfo) // <----??? 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return left.Equals(right);
}
```

It doesn't look like an accidental bug, at least until there was assumption that all instances of `RuntimeMethodInfo` are cached and there newer will be two different instances for the same method. In that case something is broken, obviously.

Any reasons behind this behavior, anyone?

P.S. Do not mark as a [duplicate], please:) The question is not about 'how to compare?'. That one was answered multiple times, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4168489/318263) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8431866/318263) for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your question is that why first compare return false and another compare return false ?

Comment: Results are 'false', 'true', not 'false', false:)
The question was about the first one. Jon Skeet already gave complete answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, it looks I was wrong with 'do not mark as duplicate'. [There is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12765804/318263) similar question, missed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your assumption for the reasoning behind it - that two `RuntimeMethodInfo` instances can be compared by reference equality - is correct. Your assumption that it's broken *isn't* correct though.

The two `MethodInfo` objects here *are* different, as they have different `ReflectedType` properties:

```
Console.WriteLine(m1.ReflectedType); // Program+A
Console.WriteLine(m2.ReflectedType); // Program+B
```